# Python async redis gives error AttributeError: __aexit__

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, async-await, sanic

I'm new to Python and trying to build a simple app to retrieve data from a redis database. But when i try to retrieve the data it gives me an "AttributeError: __aexit_" error.

Does anyone have an idea what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json
import redis

app = Sanic()

# request.args['token']

@app.route('/<id>')
async def test(request, id):
    async with redis.StrictRedis(host='0.0.0.0', port=6379, db=0) as r:
        data = await r.get("test")
        # print(data)

    return json({
        'data': data
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9988)
```

Error traceback:

```
[17203] [ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 556, in handle_request
    response = await response
  File "main.py", line 11, in test
    async with redis.StrictRedis(host='0.0.0.0', port=6379, db=0) as r:
AttributeError: __aexit__
```

Comment: It was a connection issue between my python app and the redis db. Issue resolved.

Answer (score -3):

You should use an async implementation of redis library like aioredis.
https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis